# Put a Colon Before an Input Field?

Tags: interaction-design

Consider the two entries on the following theoretical form,

`Name        _______________`

or

`Name:       _______________`

Which is more correct?

Comment: I believe this question was answered previously here: [Should label and field be separated with colon?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/should-label-and-field-be-separated-with-colon)

Answer (score 2):

Pick one and [keep it consistent](https://medium.com/@marvinvista/ux-101-6-consistency-is-key-ae35bca101b3#.xcojz0hyx). There is no "more correct" instance.

That said, does the colon provide any help to the user? Maybe so in the case of...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52VXq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

... where the transition between label and input is less clear.

Not so much in the case of...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feF35E.png)</sup>

... where the input field boards are a clear demarcation already. The colon really doesn't get in the way, but it isn't bringing a whole lot to the party either.